# Operating System Kernel assembly meaning?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, kernel

**Question 1.**
Whats the meaning of

asm volatile ("ljmp %0, $1f\n 1:\n" :: "i" (KERNEL_CS));

My guess is setting %cs as KERNEL_CS,but what about the immediate number $1f?

**Question 2.**

If we can use `jmp label` to jump to some label,why do we bother writing `jmp label f` or `jmp label b`?

**Question 3.**

Can my kernel program use `asm volatile ("ljmp %0, $1f\n 1:\n" :: "i" (USER_CS));` to change the privilege level to ring 3 at ring 0?I did this in my ISR,and I got General Protection Error.But I think my %cs and %ip are in valid exeutable and readeble memory segment after jmp,because my GDT is something like this

```
static struct segdesc gdt[] = {
SEG_NULL,
[SEG_KTEXT] = SEG(STA_X | STA_R, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, DPL_KERNEL),
[SEG_KDATA] = SEG(STA_W, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, DPL_KERNEL),
[SEG_UTEXT] = SEG(STA_X | STA_R, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, DPL_USER),
[SEG_UDATA] = SEG(STA_W, 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFF, DPL_USER),
[SEG_TSS]    = SEG_NULL,
```

};

Both KERNEL TEXT ,DATA and USER TEXT ,DATA segment are strating from the same address and have the same size.

Comment: The code is using unnamed local labels. They come in handy if you want to avoid name collision. You can only use `b` (back) and `f` (forward) with such local labels.

Comment: but $1 is an immediate number,if its a label,why not 1f instead?

Comment: That's just a syntax peculiarity of at&t far jump.

Comment: Basically, the AT&T assembler was never designed to actually use segmentation, so anything involving segmentation is a bit clunky.  Here, a long jump is implemented as an instruction taking two immediates as that's simpler to implement in the assembler for an instruction used about once in the kernel.

Comment: Got it,thank you very much

Comment: Regarding the #GP, the `jmp` instruction can only be used to jump to same-privilege segments (in protected mode) unless the target code segment is conforming. To drop privileges you can use the RPL field (check the rules though, I can't remember them all off the top of my head) or a return.

Comment: What is #GP...I think only %ds,%ss etc. have RPL,how to set that?

Comment: The standard abbreviation for your "and I got *General Protection Error*."